# Как определить когда показ рекламы завершен? Unity Ads

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, ads

В игре присутствует вознаграждаемая реклама (можно возродиться посмотрев видео).
 Для рекламы используется Unity Ads.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject playerPrefab;

    public void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize("1505242", true);
    }

    public void ShowRewardedAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            Advertisement.Show("rewardedVideo");

            Reborn();
        }
        else
        {
            TipManager.ShowMessage("Sorry, advertisment is not available. Check your connection.");
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что пока игрок смотрит рекламу, его успевают убить. 
Как сделать так, чтобы метод `Reborn()` вызывался после того, как пользователь посмотрит видео?

Comment: первый же запрос в гугл дает отличную официальную справку - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Advertisements.Advertisement.Show.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока смотрите рекламу в unity редакторе, то игра продолжает идти, не дожидаясь её конца. Можно отдельно скомпилить вашу игру, и вы увидите, что игра будет приостановлена во время показа рекламы.

Надеюсь, я правильно понял вопрос :)